# How do you debug SIGABRT

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I am getting the Stack trace shown below when I startup my application. I'm at a loss for how to find out what is causing. It. I look at all the entry points into my application, but while they stay in the same classes the entry point moves around. It leads me to believe that the way to interpret this is as a dump of all the active running threads?  Is this correct?

Some background about what is going on, this only seems to happen when my application is downloading a bunch of files it needs via OkHttp.  So there are 2-3 files it downloads in parallel and unzips to start up.  If I have already processed these files on a previous run I don't have the issues.

Another thing to note, this only seems to happen, when the device is being launched and debugged from Android Studio (2.2). It's possible that it happens when not attached, but I have not seen it.

Last, this is also only a problem on Android N

```
Runtime aborting...
Aborting thread:
"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 WaitingForDebuggerSend (still starting up)
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x7f74c0e000
  | sysTid=23054 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f7bb07450
  | state=R schedstat=( 686048383 171778965 676 ) utm=58 stm=9 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f7ba09000-0x7f7ba0b000 stackSize=1021KB
  | held mutexes= "abort lock"
  native: #00 pc 0000000000479ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000479eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
  native: #02 pc 000000000044e260  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
  native: #03 pc 000000000043c33c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+56)
  native: #04 pc 000000000043c1b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+668)
  native: #05 pc 000000000042fd34  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+144)
  native: #06 pc 00000000000e4d78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1208)
  native: #07 pc 00000000002f5f48  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEm+1000)
  native: #08 pc 00000000002f5468  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEm+124)
  native: #09 pc 00000000002f4d20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEm+248)
  native: #10 pc 00000000002f9d0c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1380)
  native: #11 pc 0000000000123ba4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+804)
  native: #12 pc 00000000001236e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1484)
  native: #13 pc 0000000000124674  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+944)
  native: #14 pc 000000000010bfb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+200)
  native: #15 pc 00000000001910a0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art19HInstructionBuilder25IsOutermostCompilingClassEt+732)
  native: #16 pc 0000000000190810  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder16BuildNewInstanceEtj+852)
  native: #17 pc 000000000018aa6c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+3436)
  native: #18 pc 0000000000189534  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+1600)
  native: #19 pc 00000000001626b8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+136)
  native: #20 pc 00000000001c113c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+3280)
  native: #21 pc 00000000001c35d8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+472)
  native: #22 pc 0000000000151bb8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+284)
  native: #23 pc 000000000030d0b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+492)
  native: #24 pc 000000000030efa4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+656)
  native: #25 pc 0000000000466dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+88)
  native: #26 pc 000000000046671c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
  native: #27 pc 000000000006863c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
  native: #28 pc 000000000001d9fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
  (no managed stack frames)
Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
All threads:
DALVIK THREADS (30):
"OkHttp http://172.31.6.143:8000/file/get/%7B%22ESN%22%3A%2235362607888370%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%22vPack%22%2C%22FolderName%22%3A%22ASR%7CEngine4%22%2C%22FileName%22%3A%22myFile1.dat%22%7D" prio=5 tid=22 Runnable
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e54310 self=0x7f5fe82c00
  | sysTid=23374 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f5eb1d450
  | state=R schedstat=( 894025544 158405362 948 ) utm=76 stm=12 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f5ea1b000-0x7f5ea1d000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  native: #00 pc 0000000000479ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000479eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
  native: #02 pc 000000000044e260  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000465ba8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+832)
  native: #04 pc 000000000044f1c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21RunCheckpointFunctionEv+192)
  native: #05 pc 00000000005483cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14JniMethodStartEPNS_6ThreadE+176)
  native: #06 pc 0000000000b29074  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_util_Log_println_1native__IILjava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2+128)
  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native method)
  at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:164)
  at com.dematic.shared.common.Logger.i(Logger.java:236)
  at com.dematic.workflow.requests.iws.FileDownloadRequest$1.onResponse(FileDownloadRequest.java:285)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"WelcomeActivity-Callback Executor" prio=5 tid=13 Runnable
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d20670 self=0x7f6201fe00
  | sysTid=23344 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f61898450
  | state=R schedstat=( 2195523146 66879832 461 ) utm=219 stm=0 core=5 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f61796000-0x7f61798000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  native: #00 pc 0000000000479ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000479eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
  native: #02 pc 000000000044e260  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000465ba8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+832)
  native: #04 pc 000000000044f1c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread21RunCheckpointFunctionEv+192)
  native: #05 pc 00000000002a66a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+2672)
  native: #06 pc 0000000000260a80  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
  native: #07 pc 000000000026670c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+184)
  native: #08 pc 0000000000286a7c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
  native: #09 pc 00000000002b8da4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE4ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+1216)
  native: #10 pc 00000000002b4ddc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb0ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+61860)
  native: #11 pc 0000000000260a80  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+484)
  native: #12 pc 00000000005497d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+832)
  native: #13 pc 00000000000db2ac  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  native: #14 pc 00000000000d1bb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+580)
  native: #15 pc 00000000000de87c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+208)
  native: #16 pc 000000000042974c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+108)
  native: #17 pc 000000000042aa50  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValuesERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDP6jvalue+372)
  native: #18 pc 000000000044a040  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6Thread14CreateCallbackEPv+1100)
  native: #19 pc 000000000006863c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
  native: #20 pc 000000000001d9fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
  at com.dematic.workflow.activities.CommunicationFragment$5.run(CommunicationFragment.java:510)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Runnable (still starting up)
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x0 self=0x7f74c0e000
  | sysTid=23054 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f7bb07450
  | state=R schedstat=( 713413070 174046620 681 ) utm=60 stm=10 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f7ba09000-0x7f7ba0b000 stackSize=1021KB
  | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
  native: #00 pc 0000000000479ebc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+220)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000479eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+216)
  native: #02 pc 000000000044e260  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+480)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000465ba8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+832)
  native: #04 pc 000000000045dd90  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+476)
  native: #05 pc 000000000045d98c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+288)
  native: #06 pc 000000000043c16c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+592)
  native: #07 pc 000000000042fd34  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+144)
  native: #08 pc 00000000000e4d78  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+1208)
  native: #09 pc 00000000002f5f48  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState19SetWaitForJdwpTokenEm+1000)
  native: #10 pc 00000000002f5468  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState24AcquireJdwpTokenForEventEm+124)
  native: #11 pc 00000000002f4d20  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState29SendRequestAndPossiblySuspendEPNS0_9ExpandBufENS0_17JdwpSuspendPolicyEm+248)
  native: #12 pc 00000000002f9d0c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState16PostClassPrepareEPNS_6mirror5ClassE+1380)
  native: #13 pc 0000000000123ba4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11DefineClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKNS_7DexFileERKNS9_8ClassDefE+804)
  native: #14 pc 00000000001236e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker26FindClassInPathClassLoaderERNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_6ThreadEPKcmNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEEPPNS8_5ClassE+1484)
  native: #15 pc 0000000000124674  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+944)
  native: #16 pc 000000000010bfb4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker11ResolveTypeERKNS_7DexFileEtNS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEENS4_INS5_11ClassLoaderEEE+200)
  native: #17 pc 00000000001910a0  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art19HInstructionBuilder25IsOutermostCompilingClassEt+732)
  native: #18 pc 0000000000190810  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder16BuildNewInstanceEtj+852)
  native: #19 pc 000000000018aa6c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+3436)
  native: #20 pc 0000000000189534  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+1600)
  native: #21 pc 00000000001626b8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+136)
  native: #22 pc 00000000001c113c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjP8_jobjectRKS5_NS_6HandleINS_6mirror8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+3280)
  native: #23 pc 00000000001c35d8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+472)
  native: #24 pc 0000000000151bb8  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+284)
  native: #25 pc 000000000030d0b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+492)
  native: #26 pc 000000000030efa4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+656)
  native: #27 pc 0000000000466dd4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+88)
  native: #28 pc 000000000046671c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+116)
  native: #29 pc 000000000006863c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
  native: #30 pc 000000000001d9fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
  (no managed stack frames)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x749f7f58 self=0x7f7c495a00
  | sysTid=23048 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f8041da98
  | state=S schedstat=( 1739699657 190601242 967 ) utm=160 stm=13 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7ff8da1000-0x7ff8da3000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
  kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x130
  kernel: futex_wait+0xfc/0x210
  kernel: do_futex+0xe0/0x920
  kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
  kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c
  native: #00 pc 000000000001bc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 00000000000e70c8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+156)
  native: #02 pc 00000000005486a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+328)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000548514  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+28)
  native: #04 pc 0000000000c2999c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_view_ThreadedRenderer_nSyncAndDrawFrame__J_3JI+184)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(Native method)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:789)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

"Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cb9160 self=0x7f721a0000
  | sysTid=23055 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f7ba06450
  | state=S schedstat=( 3247347 22885365 73 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f7b90c000-0x7f7b90e000 stackSize=1005KB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
  kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0xec/0x1dc
  kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0xd8/0x134
  kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c
  native: #00 pc 000000000006ac54  /system/lib64/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+8)
  native: #01 pc 0000000000024d00  /system/lib64/libc.so (sigwait+120)
  native: #02 pc 000000000044093c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9SignalSet4WaitEv+48)
  native: #03 pc 00000000004403f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13WaitForSignalEPNS_6ThreadERNS_9SignalSetE+232)
  native: #04 pc 000000000043e98c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+400)
  native: #05 pc 000000000006863c  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+208)
  native: #06 pc 000000000001d9fc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)
  (no managed stack frames)

"OkHttp http://172.31.6.143:8000/file/get/%7B%22ESN%22%3A%2235362607888370%22%2C%22Type%22%3A%22vPack%22%2C%22FolderName%22%3A%22Files%22%2C%22FileName%22%3A%22my_file2.zip%22%7D" prio=5 tid=28 Runnable
  | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e544c0 self=0x7f5fe83600
  | sysTid=23376 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f5dc8f450
  | state=R schedstat=( 855558938 180884175 597 ) utm=80 stm=4 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f5db8d000-0x7f5db8f000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)

  at java.util.Calendar.setFieldsComputed(Calendar.java:1596)
  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:2257)
  at java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1122)
  at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(GregorianCalendar.java:622)
  at java.util.Calendar.createCalendar(Calendar.java:1025)
  at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1019)
  at okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog.run(AsyncTimeout.java:286)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=18 TimedWaiting
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cfa9d0 self=0x7f62100600
  | sysTid=23353 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f60d7f450
  | state=S schedstat=( 3985209 2741668 39 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f60c7d000-0x7f60c7f000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
  kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x130
  kernel: futex_wait+0xfc/0x210
  kernel: futex_wait_restart+0x54/0x80
  kernel: sys_restart_syscall+0x18/0x24
  kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c
  native: #00 pc 000000000001bc70  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
  native: #01 pc 00000000000e7668  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadEli+176)
  native: #02 pc 000000000037947c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+676)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000000980  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+140)
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x0eb4e8d7> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
  - locked <0x0eb4e8d7> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=19 TimedWaiting
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12cfaa60 self=0x7f74c2e600
  | sysTid=23354 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f60c7a450
  | state=S schedstat=( 3302761 2719690 40 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f60b78000-0x7f60b7a000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
  kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x130
  kernel: futex_wait+0xfc/0x210
  kernel: futex_wait_restart+0x54/0x80
  kernel: sys_restart_syscall+0x18/0x24
  kernel: cpu_switch_to+0x48/0x4c
  native: #00 pc 000000000001bc70  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
  native: #01 pc 00000000000e7668  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadEli+176)
  native: #02 pc 000000000037947c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+676)
  native: #03 pc 0000000000000980  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+140)
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x0f42d5c4> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
  - locked <0x0f42d5c4> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

"hwuiTask1" prio=5 tid=20 Native
  | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d854c0 self=0x7f74d58a00
  | sysTid=23355 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f60b55450
  | state=S schedstat=( 1874432 2351405 40 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f60a5b000-0x7f60a5d000 stackSize=1005KB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0x98
  kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd4/0x130
  kernel: futex_wait+0xfc/0x210
```

Comment: I have same problem, just on Android N (7.1.1), Nexus 5X